# Unable to display video component correctly inside react-bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, webrtc, html5-video, react-bootstrap

I am trying to build a two party calling application using WebRTC. My design is

- On a non mobile device the local stream will display on the left and the remote stream will display on the right in a larger screen. They will be side by side.
- On a mobile device the streams will be stacked. The local stream being smaller.

I am using react-bootstrap to position my two streams inside columns.

The issue I face is that when one party is on a non mobile device, the stream from mobile device on the non mobile device far exceeds the size of the window. Please see image below for example.

[image]

```
<Container fluid>
<Row>
            <Col sm={12} lg={2}>    //localStream sm={12} will ensure that the video will be be stacked on mobile 
                    <video style={{width: '50%', height : '100%', objectFit : 'contain'}} muted ref={userVideo} autoPlay playsInline />
            </Col>  
            <Col sm={12} lg={10} style={{ maxWidth : '80vw', maxHeight: '80vh'}}> //Temp attempt to limit the size of the remote stream when received from  mobile
                <video style={{ width: '100%',  height : 'auto', objectFit: 'contain'}} playsInline autoPlay ref={ref} />
            </Col>
        </Row>
</Container>
```

I believe the issue is that the height is auto on the remote stream and filling up the column. I have tired to enforce a maxWidth and maxHeight on the actual column but is having little effect.

I have tired a number of different combinations of video widths and heights.

Any suggestions or pointers?